# PHP + Forms + wordpress: Removing accented characters from $_GET['s'] on search submit

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, get, special-characters

I'm using the following search function in my theme.

I want to manipulate the $_GET variable that gets put in the URL by removing any accented characters like é, ó, í, etc. The point is to not have any special characters in the URL. Wordpress has a function `remove_accents` which accomplishes the switching of an accented to a non-accented character, but I'm unsure of the rest...

Thanks!

How can I do this?

```
// SEARCH FORM
function bam_search_form($echo = true) {
    do_action( 'get_search_form' );

    $uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

    global $blog_id;
    $searchtext = 'Buscá';

    $search_form_template = locate_template('searchform.php');
    if ( '' != $search_form_template ) {
        require($search_form_template);
        return;
    }

    $form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '" >
    <div><input type="text" value="'.$searchtext.'" name="s" class="s c1 caps c3h" />';

    $form .= form_extend($uri, $form);

    $form .= '<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="c1" value="." />
    </div>
    </form>';

    if ( $echo )
        echo apply_filters('get_search_form', $form);
    else
        return apply_filters('get_search_form', $form);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a submit javascript function to replace the search string characters

change

```
$form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '" >
    <div><input type="text" value="'.$searchtext.'" name="s" class="s c1 caps c3h" />';
```

to

```
$form = '<form role="search" onsubmit="changeSearch()" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '" >
    <div><input type="text" id="searchvalue" value="'.$searchtext.'" name="s" class="s c1 caps c3h" />';
```

and add this javascript

```
function changeSearch(){
    var field = document.getElementById('searchvalue');
    var r= field.value.toLowerCase();
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/\s/g),"");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/[àáâãäå]/g),"a");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/æ/g),"ae");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/ç/g),"c");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/[èéêë]/g),"e");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/[ìíîï]/g),"i");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/ñ/g),"n");                
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/[òóôõö]/g),"o");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/œ/g),"oe");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/[ùúûü]/g),"u");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/[ýÿ]/g),"y");
    r = r.replace(new RegExp(/\W/g),"");
    field.value = r;
}
```

You can also add more replace pattern.

Comment: thanks Ciro! ideally I'm looking for something that works with or without JS